# Как отключить масштабирование Placemark Яндекс карты API

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

При масштабировании карты, созданная метка изменяет свой размер относительно карты. То бишь при отдалении размер метки увеличивается. Как сделать чтобы размер метки был постоянным не зависимо от масштаба карты  ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Метки и должны быть хорошо видны при любом масштабе. Это площадные объекты, как ваша окружность или ломаная меняют размеры. Нужно, чтобы метки были привязаны к масштабу, делайте их полигонами. Ну или можете заморочиться и отслеживая изменение масштаба переопределяйте размеры меток на карте, наверное.

Comment: @YaCor' а если мне нужно добавить иконку png ? Ее тоже полигонами рисовать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Метки**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark/) – элементы, которые должны быть видны на любом масштабе. Когда их много становится на экране, их объединяют в [**кластеры**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_custom_icon). Если метки должны занимать площадь, их следует рисовать [**полигонами**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon) нужной формы и цвета.

Если всё же эти метки должны быть растровыми, а не векторными, следует использовать метод, предложенный Яндексом в примере "[**Настройка размера метки на разных зумах**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/scalable_placemarks)". Привяжите её макет (и размер) к **zoom** карты.